# A word that rhymes with Loyalty, begins with L and means or synonymous with greed?

Tags: single-word-requests

To all you wordsmiths out here , can you suggest a word that rhymes with Loyalty, begins with L and means greed?

Comment: Is this a word you know exists, or one you're hoping does?

Comment: According to a [couple](http://wikirhymer.com/words/loyalty) of [online](http://www.rhymezone.com/r/rhyme.cgi?&typeofrhyme=perfect&loc=moreideas&Word=loyalty) rhyming [sources](http://rhymebrain.com/en/What_rhymes_with_loyalty.html), there are only two pure rhymes to loyalty: royalty and disloyalty.  Looks like you are s.o.l.

Comment: re-reading your request,  "larceny" as in theft, rhymes a little bit in terms of the y at the end and the number of syllables.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps "Larceny" ?

It comes close to rhyming with "loyalty" with the same number of syllables and the "y" at the end.

Larceny means "theft" of personal goods which is in the greater area of "greed".

> [**larceny**  - from Merriam-Websters online](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/larceny?s=t)
>
> 1.
>   the wrongful taking and carrying away of the personal goods of another from his or her possession with intent to convert them to the taker's own use.

Answer (score 0):

My big thesaurus (1987 based on Roget's) has nothing that meets both criteria. On the rhyme, your best options are *cupidity*, *rapacity*, *venality*, or *voracity*

Starting with *L* there's even less: *longing* and *lust * are the best.